# Problem registering object and interface on the startup file more specifically in the ConfigureServices method, the app does not execute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Well, I have created an application to start on ASP net core 3.1 from scratch, I have created an API application and I have already created some layers to have better control on my application, However, when I created my object with its interface and registered them in the startup file on this way:

```
services.AddScoped<IMySpaceService, MySpaceService>();
```

I have gotten this error when I run the application:

> Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MySpaceService.Services.Interfaces.IMySpaceService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType:

this is my code:

```
public class MySpaceService: IMySpaceService
{
    private IMySpaceRepository _mySpaceRepository;

    public MySpaceService(IMySpaceRepository mySpaceRepository)
    {
        _mySpaceRepository = mySpaceRepository;
    }

    public IList<MySpaceDto> getSpaces()
    {
        List<MySpaceDto> spaces = new List<MySpaceDto>();
        var data = _mySpaceRepository.getSpaces();
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            SpaceDto spaceDto = new SpaceDto();
            spaceDto.Identification = item.Identification;
            spaceDto.Name = item.Name;
            spaces.Add(spaceDto);
        }

        return spaces;

    }
}
```

My startup code:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddScoped<IMySpaceService, MySpaceService>();
        services.AddScoped<IMySpaceRepository, MySpaceRepository>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

Any Ideas about it?.

Comment: Can you show us `MySpaceService` code?

Comment: Has `IMySpaceRepository` also been registered?

Comment: **Yes, I have already registered all objects either interfaces that I am using. the problem happens when I register any objects on configureServices method when I comment all my registers the app works**

Comment: show us please your Startup.cs

Comment: Does MySpaceRepository have any dependencies?

Comment: @LuisV Review the object graph, one of your constructors either does not have a dependency registered, or one of the constructors in the object graph is throwing an exception when the container tries to resolve the top level object.

Answer (score 0):

Your `MySpaceService` has only one constructor with parameter `IMySpaceRepository`. You need to register your repository as well:

```
services.AddScoped<IMySpaceRepository, MySpaceRepository>();
services.AddScoped<IMySpaceService, MySpaceService>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, definitely the problem was that I had not registered yet a dependency, however, the dependency that I hadn't registered was "Dbcontext" and I am calling it from my repository class on the constructor. Therefore, I have to say that your comments helped me to solve my problem because finally, it was a problem with the dependency that didn't register.

I had to do this on my startup file:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<ExampleContext>(
                options => options.UseMySql("Server=localhost;port=3306;Database=exampleDB;User=UserRegistered;Password=*******", mySqlOptions => mySqlOptions
                   .ServerVersion(new ServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 18), ServerType.MySql))));
```